# Solving $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (u\ \text{sign}(x)) =-1$ with some initial condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transport-equation

I need some help to solve this transport equation 
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (u\ \text{sign}(x)) =-1$$
with initial condition $$ u_0(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if } x\in [-2,-1]\cup [1,2] \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$

The solution is computable and, for our data, all I have to do is compute this expression
$$ u(t,x)= u_0(X(0;t,x))J(0;t,x) +\int_0^t -1\ ds =   u_0(X(0;t,x))J(0;t,x) -t$$
where $X(\xi;t,x)$ is the characteristic curve with initial condition $X(t)=x$, that is,
$$ (1)\ \ \begin{cases} \frac{dX(\xi;t,x)}{d\xi} = \text{sign}(X(\xi)) \\ X(t)=x \end{cases} $$
and $J(\xi;t,x)$ is, in this case, $J(\xi;t,x) = \det (\frac{dX(\xi;t,x)}{dx})$. I hace problems to solve (1) (of course in the weak sense), and therefore, also to calculate $J(\xi;t,x)$. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which title do you suggest?

Comment: It's not an answer; it's a comment. I have edited the title.

Answer (score 2):

This won't be a very rigorous answer, but let's see intuitively what happens. Using the definition of the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function), we have
\begin{aligned}
u_t + u_x &= -1 &&\text{if}\quad x>0 \\
u_t \phantom{+u_x} &= -1 &&\text{if}\quad x=0 \\
u_t - u_x &= -1 &&\text{if}\quad x<0
\end{aligned}
Thus, using the method of characteristics in a piece-wise manner, we find
\begin{aligned}
u(x,t) &= u_0(x-t) - t &&\text{if}\quad x>0 \\
u(0,t) &= -t &&\text{if}\quad x=0 \\
u(x,t) &= u_0(x+t) -t &&\text{if}\quad x<0
\end{aligned}
Finally, the provided initial data $u_0$ leads to
$$
u(x,t) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
&1-t &&\text{if } x\in [-2-t, -1-t]\cup [1+t, 2+t] \\
&{-t} &&\text{otherwise}
\end{aligned}\right.
$$